# Channel capacity

Tags: self-study, mutual-information

> A binary channel is described with following conditional probabilities:
>
> $p(y_1|x_1)=1, \quad p(y_1|x_2)=p(y_2|x_2)=\frac{1}{2}$
>
> Additionally, we know that "1" appears 13 times more frequently than "0" in the output.
> What is a capacity of the channel?

My question is if the additional piece of information is really relevant as I get two different solutions with and without using it ( I put $p(y=1)=13 \cdot p(y=0)$ )?

P.S. Correct answer is when omit the tip.

Comment: What appears at the channel output is determined by the distribution of the input and the channel transition probabilities. However, the channel capacity is determined by the channel transition probabilities alone. Are you sure you are not being asked what rate of transmission is achievable given that the input is constrained to be such that the channel output distribution is as given?

Comment: Nope, I got to find a capacity of this particulare channel. I wonder if information that "1" in the output appears 13 times more frequently than "0" implicate that probability of appearing "1" is 13 times higher than "0"?